# Why does my Turtle-drawing -program die after 2 movements

Tags: python, python-turtle

This code was supposed to A) create a grid (which it does) and B) move diagonally while drawing its path & change directions whenever it hits wall & stop moving when it returns to its original spot.

Part A works, but part B finishes after 2 movements, thinking it's back to its original place, even though **it definitely is not.**

[Screenshot of the program after it's "done"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ3fI.png)

Any advice or other info you need?

```
import turtle as t
from time import sleep

""" HOW TO USE:
    - Set the size variables
    - Every movement is in 10-step increments
    - 

"""


""" Size variables """
top_x_border = 100
bottom_x_border = 0
top_y_border = 80
bottom_y_border = 0



# Creating the screen
sc = t.Screen()
sc.title("Kelttiläiset solmut")
sc.bgcolor("white")
sc.setup(width = 0.7, height = 0.8)
sc.tracer(2)
sc.delay(10000) 



# Creating the drawer-turtle
drawer = t.Turtle()
change_x = 10
change_y = 10


""" 

Functions

"""



""" Methods """
# method to draw y-axis lines
def drawy(steps, val):
    
    # line
    drawer.forward(steps)
    
    # set position
    drawer.up()
    drawer.setpos(val,steps)
    drawer.down()
    
    # another line
    drawer.backward(steps)
    
    # set position again
    drawer.up()
    drawer.setpos(val+10,0)
    drawer.down()
    
    
    
# method to draw x-axis lines
def drawx(steps, val):
    
    # line
    drawer.forward(steps)
    
    # set position
    drawer.up()
    drawer.setpos(steps,val)
    drawer.down()
    
    # another line
    drawer.backward(steps)
    
    # set position again
    drawer.up()
    drawer.setpos(0,val+10)
    drawer.down()



# Whole Grid
def grid():
    drawer.speed(100)
    drawer.left(90)

    # y lines
    for i in range(top_x_border // 10):
        drawy(top_x_border, 10*(i+1))

    # set position for x lines 
    drawer.right(90)
    drawer.up()
    drawer.setpos(0,0)
    drawer.down()
    
    # x lines
    for i in range(top_x_border // 10):
        drawx(top_x_border, 10*(i+1))

    # hide the turtle
    drawer.hideturtle()


# actually drawing the thing
def actually_do_stuff():
    global change_x
    global change_y
    global top_x_border
    global bottom_x_border
    global top_y_border
    global bottom_y_border    
    
    for i in (1, 101):
        # Move the drawer
        print("{}x{}".format(drawer.xcor(),drawer.ycor()))
    
        drawer.goto(drawer.xcor()+change_x, drawer.ycor()+change_y)
        
        """
        # Check if back at start
        if [ drawer.xcor() == Start["x"] ] and [ drawer.ycor() == Start["x"] ]:
            break
        """
        
        print("top/bottom_x_borders: ", top_x_border, bottom_x_border)
        print("{}x{}".format(drawer.xcor(),drawer.ycor()))
        
        """
        # Check for collisions with the borders
        if [ drawer.xcor() <= top_x_border ] or [ drawer.xcor() >= bottom_x_border ]:
            change_x *= -1
        elif [ drawer.ycor() <= top_y_border ] or [drawer.ycor() >= bottom_y_border]:
            change_y *= -1
        """

# Methods end 


""" ACTUAL THINGS HAPPENING """

drawer.color('gray')
grid()

#go to starting position
drawer.penup()
drawer.goto(bottom_x_border, bottom_y_border+10)
drawer.pendown()

#mark starting position
Start = {}
Start["x"] = drawer.xcor()
Start["y"] = drawer.ycor()

# Actually draw what you wanted
drawer.color('red')
actually_do_stuff()

drawer.hideturtle()
sc.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 3):

it stops at (20, 30) after 2 moves because in `actually_do_stuff()` you wrote `for i in (1, 101)`, thats 2 moves right?

I think that should be `for i in range(1, 101)`, so it continues to move for 100 times.